# Changing the default Aptana IP address

Tags: ruby, aptana, aptana3

I want to change the default IP to 127.0.0.1 or localhost instead of script/rails server http://0.0.0.0:3000.

How I can do that in Aptana 3?

```
script/rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.3 application starting in development on **http://0.0.0.0:3000**
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-05-04 21:41:46] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-05-04 21:41:46] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
[2012-05-04 21:41:46] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=9588 port=3000
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the command line options:

```
script/rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 80
```

Comment: @Gainster - I'm honestly not that experienced with the Rails development server. I've always developed with a local Apache/Passenger setup so I don't have to start/stop my server and I can use local domain names. However, you could probably either set up your own custom script in the `scripts` folder to start up the server with default options or there may be a way to set these in your environment configuration. Someone with more Rails experience may correct me on that. ;)